# Bash function to ssh with command

Tags: linux, bash

I have simple script to check for uptime of bunch of hosts. But ssh command is taking 'uptime' command also as a hostname and throwing error after first iteration.

```
while read line
do

  echo "Turning off Monitoring for Host: $line"
  monitoring_off

  check_uptime $line

done < "$HOSTFILE"

check_uptime() {
 ssh $1 'uptime'
}
```

Here is the output of my script execution:

```
*****************************
14:08:44 up 203 days,  2:34,  1 user,  load average: 1.22, 1.11, 0.79

ssh: Could not resolve hostname uptime: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Could you please me in locating my mistake in here

Comment: What data are you looping through?  If your $1 is empty (i.e. a blank line), it could be throwing that error.

Comment: @WraezorSharp HOSTFILE is variable holding list of IP addresses

Comment: Your HOSTFILE probably contains a blank line. Try using `ssh "$1" 'uptime'` instead and you'll probably see another error message.

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800225/shell-script-while-read-line-loop-stops-after-the-first-line

Taken from the answer:

The problem is that [the function] runs `ssh` commands and by default `ssh` reads from stdin which is your input file. As a result, you only see the first line processed, because `ssh` consumes the rest of the file and your while loop terminates.

To prevent this, pass the `-n` option to your `ssh` command to make it read from `/dev/null` instead of stdin.

```
check_uptime() {
 ssh -n $1 'uptime'
}
```